# React Native - Prefilled values in dynamic(generated) TextInputs

Tags: reactjs, react-native

The user generate's a profile that he can choose.

The profile looks like this:

```
{
    currency: 'CZK',
    name: "Profil 2",
    items: ["5000","700"]
}
```

Based on count of items in items, the app  generates Text Inputs (in this case two Text Inputs)
I need to prefill the values (5000 and 700 in this case) in the two TextInputs and allow the user to edit the text input.

My TextInput (generated in map function)

```
<TextInput key={index+1}
    style={styles.customInput}                                
    onChangeText={(text) => this.updateState(index, text)}
    value={this.state.text}
/>
```

updateState function

```
updateState = (index,value) => {
    const text = [this.state.text];
    text[index] = value;
    this.setState({ text: text });
}
```

When I use value={this.state.text} -> its blank but the user can edit the text

When I use item ( value={item} )(variable that contains the string I need to prefill) -> its prefilled but the user can't edit (because it's always setting the input value to the string )

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting the values correctly in state for textinputs

**Try this**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet,TextInput } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {

  state = {
    currency: 'CZK',
    name: "Profil 2",
    items: ["5000","700"]
  }

  updateState = (index,value) => {
    const items = this.state.items;
    items[index] = value;
    this.setState({ items });

 }  

  render() {
    const {items} = this.state;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {items.map((item,index) => <TextInput style={styles.textInput} value={item} onChangeText={(text) => this.updateState(index, text)} />)}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: 20,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  textInput:{padding:20,borderColor:"red",borderWidth:1}
});
```

Snack Link : https://snack.expo.io/@mehran.khan/multipletextinputs